# Delphi JEDI JCL crash Windows 7 on installation

Tags: delphi, windows-7, installation, crash, jedi

I search for a solution.
We have Delphi 6 Prof on Win7/X64.

When I tried four times to install JCL, the Windows crash with Blue Death.
I set the installer.exe to "Windows XP mode" but nothing happens.

How can I install JCL to my Delphi, and what CAN cause full crash in Win7?

Thanks:
   dd

Comment: You might want to have a look at the newsgroups at news.delphi-jedi.org, there are many installation problem threads. I never came across a BSOD though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely this is a hardware fault. Run diagnostics on your disk. Hope that your backup works!

Comment: I'd agree, otherwise it should most probably throw an exception and exit.

Comment: This is not hardware fault. I ran the checkdisk 3 times. And I started the installer again, it caused "System Service Exception".

Comment: @durumdara How could it not either be a hardware fault or a driver fault. That's where BSODs come from 99.999% of the time. Bug in Windows? Not so likely.

Comment: Hi! Today I started a test: compile it in Safe mode. And it succeeds! So only one thing I need: determine which system component cause this problem... :-( Thanks: dd